# RabbitMQ RPC with exchanges trouble

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

so I have been following this tutorial: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html, but I cant get it to work with a direct exchange.

Can someone help me out please by modifying the code so that it works with a direct exchange.

My objective: the user can chose which machine to send to, When they choose i want to bind to that machine and just send it to that machine. But it doesn't seem to be working when i change the queue declare to exchange declare.  Any help would be greatly appriciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In RabbitMQ you publish messages to exchanges, so the code you are seeing in the tutorial: `channel.basicPublish("", "rpc_queue", props, message.getBytes());`, means: send a message to the exchange `""`, using routing key `"rpc_queue"`. That's the default or anon exchange discussed in tutorial one.

So if you want to send a message to a direct exchange, just change the empty exchange name for your exchange name.

Now, why do you want to do it that way? Why can't you instead of declaring an `"rpc_queue"`, you declare a queue per machine, and address them by their names, in `basicPublish`?